# String Concatenation in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've to concatenate a sql query with a parameter. My t-sql code:

```
DECLARE @TESTPARAM varchar(20)
DECLARE @SQLQUERY varchar(250)
SET @TESTPARAM = 'test'
SET @SQLQUERY = 'SELECT ' + @TESTPARAM+ '
```

So I want to have the value in the select query and not the column.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Kind regards, pro

Comment: Hi sll what is not clear? I want to have the value test in my select statement - like this: select 'test'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @TESTPARAM varchar(20)
DECLARE @SQLQUERY varchar(250)
SET @TESTPARAM = 'test'
SET @SQLQUERY = 'SELECT ''' + @TESTPARAM + ''''
```

Comment: @pro: Please remember to Accept answers that meet your requirements.

Comment: @Mark - I couldn't accept it within four minutes after I've voted for it. But now I've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

The single quote  is an escape character for the single quote, that's why when you put '' in a string it will actually be stored as ' in your string, such as \\ in any C-syntax language =-). I thought I might add that.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TESTPARAM varchar(200)
DECLARE @SQLQUERY varchar(250)
SET @TESTPARAM = 'test'
SET @SQLQUERY = 'SELECT ' +  @TESTPARAM 
SELECT @SQLQUERY
```

Comment: Hi praveen, thanks for your code. unfortunately it's not the solution, because it is selected the following value: 'SELECT test' and I need 'Select 'test''.